# R: LIME returns error on different feature numbers when it's not the case

Tags: r, text-classification, quanteda, lime

I'm building a text classifier of Clinton & Trump tweets (data can be found on [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/benhamner/clinton-trump-tweets/data#) ).

I'm doing EDA and modelling using `quanteda` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(quanteda)
library(lime)

#data prep
tweet_csv <- read_csv("tweets.csv")
tweet_data <- tweet_csv %>% 
  select(author = handle,
     text,
     retweet_count,
     favorite_count,
     source_url,
     timestamp = time) %>% 
mutate(date = as_date(str_sub(timestamp, 1, 10)),
     hour = hour(hms(str_sub(timestamp, 12, 19))),
     tweet_num = row_number()) %>% 
select(-timestamp)

# creating corpus and dfm
tweet_corpus <- corpus(tweet_data)

edited_dfm <- dfm(tweet_corpus, remove_url = TRUE, remove_punct = TRUE,     remove = stopwords("english"))

set.seed(32984)
trainIndex <- sample.int(n = nrow(tweet_csv), size =     floor(.8*nrow(tweet_csv)), replace = F)

train_dfm <- edited_dfm[as.vector(trainIndex), ]
train_raw <- tweet_data[as.vector(trainIndex), ]
train_label <- train_raw$author == "realDonaldTrump"

test_dfm <- edited_dfm[-as.vector(trainIndex), ]
test_raw <- tweet_data[-as.vector(trainIndex), ]
test_label <- test_raw$author == "realDonaldTrump"

# making sure train and test sets have the same features
test_dfm <- dfm_select(test_dfm, train_dfm)

# using quanteda's NB model
nb_model <- quanteda::textmodel_nb(train_dfm, train_labels)
nb_preds <- predict(nb_model, test_dfm) 


# defining textmodel_nb as classification model
class(nb_model)

model_type.textmodel_nb_fitted <- function(x, ...) {
  return("classification")
}

# a wrapper-up function for data preprocessing

get_matrix <- function(df){
  corpus <- corpus(df)
  dfm <- dfm(corpus, remove_url = TRUE, remove_punct = TRUE, remove = stopwords("english"))
}
```

then I define the explainer - no problems here:

```
explainer <- lime(train_raw[1:5],
              model = nb_model,
              preprocess = get_matrix)
```

But when I run an explainer, even on exactly same dataset as in `explainer`, I get an error:

```
explanation <- lime::explain(train_raw[1:5], 
                              explainer, 
                              n_labels = 1,
                              n_features = 6,
                              cols = 2,
                              verbose = 0)
```

> Error in predict.textmodel_nb_fitted(x, newdata = newdata, type = type,  : 
>     feature set in newdata different from that in training set

Does it have something to do with `quanteda` and dfms? I honestly don't see why this should happen. Any help will be great, thanks!

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44141997.  You need to use `dfm_select()` on your `newdata` argument to `predict()`.

Comment: Hi @Ken, yes, I've seen this question but the answer provided by Weihuang Wong fixed the issue. However, as you can see from the below comments, I had to change the analysis steps a bit and this caused different problems. You can check out a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50290782/r-problems-applying-lime-to-quanteda-text-model), I'll appreciate any hints!! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can trace the error to `predict_model`, which calls `predict.textmodel_nb_fitted` (I used only the first 10 rows of `train_raw` to speed up computation):

```
traceback()
# 7: stop("feature set in newdata different from that in training set")
# 6: predict.textmodel_nb_fitted(x, newdata = newdata, type = type, 
#        ...)
# 5: predict(x, newdata = newdata, type = type, ...)
# 4: predict_model.default(explainer$model, case_perm, type = o_type)
# 3: predict_model(explainer$model, case_perm, type = o_type)
# 2: explain.data.frame(train_raw[1:10, 1:5], explainer, n_labels = 1, 
#        n_features = 5, cols = 2, verbose = 0)
# 1: lime::explain(train_raw[1:10, 1:5], explainer, n_labels = 1, 
#        n_features = 5, cols = 2, verbose = 0)
```

The problem is that `predict.textmodel_nb_fitted` expects a dfm, not a data frame. For example, `predict(nb_model, test_raw[1:5])` gives you the same "feature set in newdata different from that in training set" error. However, `explain` takes a data frame as its `x` argument.

A solution is to write a custom `textmodel_nb_fitted` method for `predict_model` that does the necessary object conversions before calling `predict.textmodel_nb_fitted`:

```
predict_model.textmodel_nb_fitted <- function(x, newdata, type, ...) {
  X <- corpus(newdata)
  X <- dfm_select(dfm(X), x$data$x)   
  res <- predict(x, newdata = X, ...)
  switch(
   type,
   raw = data.frame(Response = res$nb.predicted, stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
   prob = as.data.frame(res$posterior.prob, check.names = FALSE)
  )  
}
```

This gives us

```
explanation <- lime::explain(train_raw[1:10, 1:5], 
                              explainer,
                              n_labels = 1,
                              n_features = 5,
                              cols = 2,
                              verbose = 0)
explanation[1, 1:5]
#       model_type case label label_prob    model_r2
# 1 classification    1 FALSE  0.9999986 0.001693861
```

Comment: Thank you, @Weihuang, indeed your answer solved the issue but I realised that LIME would not look at text features only and printing explanations was challenging. I rephrased my question and changed a couple of steps to fix it, but this time I'm getting different errors. I posted a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50290782/6327771) so I wonder if you could have a look at it? Thanks again for your help, it's invaluable!