# R: problems applying LIME to quanteda text model

Tags: r, text, text-classification, quanteda, lime

it's a modified version of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50273919/6327771): I'm trying to run LIME on my `quanteda` text model that feeds off [Trump & Clinton tweets data](https://www.kaggle.com/benhamner/clinton-trump-tweets/data#). I run it following an example given by Thomas Pedersen in his [Understanding LIME](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lime/vignettes/Understanding_lime.html) and useuful SO answer provided by [@Weihuang Wong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50275665/6327771):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(quanteda)
library(lime)

#data prep
tweet_csv <- read_csv("tweets.csv")

# creating corpus and dfm for train and test sets

get_matrix <- function(df){
  corpus <- quanteda::corpus(df)
  dfm <- quanteda::dfm(corpus, remove_url = TRUE, remove_punct = TRUE,     remove = stopwords("english"))
}

set.seed(32984)
trainIndex <- sample.int(n = nrow(tweet_csv), size =     floor(.8*nrow(tweet_csv)), replace = F)

train_dfm <- get_matrix(tweet_csv$text[trainIndex])
train_raw <- tweet_csv[, c("text", "tweet_num")][as.vector(trainIndex), ]
train_labels <- tweet_csv$author[as.vector(trainIndex)] == "realDonaldTrump"

test_dfm <- get_matrix(tweet_csv$text[-trainIndex])
test_raw <- tweet_csv[, c("text", "tweet_num")][-as.vector(trainIndex), ]
test_labels <- tweet_csv$author[-as.vector(trainIndex)] == "realDonaldTrump"

#### make sure that train & test sets have exactly same features
test_dfm <- dfm_select(test_dfm, train_dfm)

### Naive Bayes model using quanteda::textmodel_nb ####
nb_model <- quanteda::textmodel_nb(train_dfm, train_labels)
nb_preds <- predict(nb_model, test_dfm) #> 0.5


# select only correct predictions
predictions_tbl <- data.frame(predict_label = nb_preds$nb.predicted,
                          actual_label = test_labels,
                          tweet_name = rownames(nb_preds$posterior.prob)
) %>%
  mutate(tweet_num = 
       as.integer(
         str_trim(
           str_replace_all(tweet_name, "text", ""))
     )) 


correct_pred <- predictions_tbl %>%
  filter(actual_label == predict_label) 

# pick a sample of tweets for explainer 
tweets_to_explain <- test_raw %>%
  filter(tweet_num %in% correct_pred$tweet_num) %>% 
  head(4)



### set up correct model class and predict functions 
class(nb_model)

model_type.textmodel_nb_fitted <- function(x, ...) {
  return("classification")
}


# have to modify the textmodel_nb_fitted so that 

predict_model.textmodel_nb_fitted <- function(x, newdata, type, ...) {
  X <- corpus(newdata)
  X <- dfm_select(dfm(X), x$data$x)   
  res <- predict(x, newdata = X, ...)
  switch(
    type,
    raw = data.frame(Response = res$nb.predicted, stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
    prob = as.data.frame(res$posterior.prob, check.names = FALSE)
  )  
}


### run the explainer - no problems here 
explainer <- lime(tweets_to_explain$text, # lime returns error on different features in explainer and explanations, even if I use the same dataset in both. Raised an issue on Github and asked a question on SO
              model = nb_model,
              preprocess = get_matrix)
```

But when I run the explainer...

```
corr_explanation <- lime::explain(tweets_to_explain$text, 
                              explainer, 
                              n_labels = 1,
                              n_features = 6,
                              cols = 2,
                              verbose = 0)
```

... I get the following error:

> Error in UseMethod("corpus") : 
>     no applicable method for 'corpus' applied to an object of class "c('dfm', 'dgCMatrix', 'CsparseMatrix', 'dsparseMatrix', 'generalMatrix', 'dCsparseMatrix', 'dMatrix', 'sparseMatrix', 'compMatrix', 'Matrix', 'xMatrix', 'mMatrix', 'Mnumeric', 'replValueSp')"

It goes back to applying `corpus()` to `newdata`:

```
5.corpus(newdata) 
4.predict_model.textmodel_nb_fitted(x = explainer$model, newdata = permutations_tokenized, 
type = o_type) 
3.predict_model(x = explainer$model, newdata = permutations_tokenized, 
type = o_type) 
2.explain.character(tweets_to_explain$text, explainer, n_labels = 1, 
n_features = 6, cols = 2, verbose = 0) 
1.lime::explain(tweets_to_explain$text, explainer, n_labels = 1, 
n_features = 6, cols = 2, verbose = 0)
```

But I don't understand why should this cause any issues as new data is a text vector?

Thanks for any hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`corpus` doesn't have to be run. Try redefining `predict_model.textmodel_nb_fitted` as follows, where the only modification is to add the `dfm_select` step:

```
predict_model.textmodel_nb_fitted <- function(x, newdata, type, ...) {
  X <- dfm_select(dfm(newdata), x$data$x)   
  res <- predict(x, newdata = X, ...)
  switch(
    type,
    raw = data.frame(Response = res$nb.predicted, stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
    prob = as.data.frame(res$posterior.prob, check.names = FALSE)
  )  
}
```

As your `traceback()` output shows, `corpus` throws an error. To debug, I inserted `print(str(newdata))` in the first line of the `predict_model.textmodel_nb_fitted` function. This shows that `newdata` is already a `dfm` object, so it can be passed directly into `predict.textmodel_nb_fitted` (after processing it with `dfm_select`).

---

In more recent versions of `quanteda`, `textmodel_nb()` returns an object of classes `textmodel_nb`,`textmodel`, and `list`. This would first require a corresponding method for `model_type`:

```
model_type.textmodel_nb <- function(x, ...) {
  return("classification")
}
```

We then also have to write a `textmodel_nb` method for `predict_model`:

```
predict_model.textmodel_nb <- function(x, newdata, type, ...) {
  X <- dfm_select(dfm(newdata), x$x)   
  res <- predict(x, newdata = X, ...)
  switch(
    type,
    raw = data.frame(Response = res$nb.predicted, stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
    prob = as.data.frame(res$posterior.prob, check.names = FALSE)
  )  
}
```

Notice that the second argument to `dfm_select` is different from that in `predict_model.textmodel_nb_fitted` (from the original version of the answer). This is because the structure of the `x` object -- the output from `textmodel_nb()` -- has changed.

Comment: OK, there's a layer of complexity to add! When I run the code from one mac `class(nb_model)` returns `"textmodel_nb_fitted" "list"` and the above code works. However, on Windows computers Macbook 2008 the output is `"textmodel_nb" "textmodel"    "list"` , why? And whether I modify predict.model and model_type to `.textmodel` or `.textmodel_nb` I still have problems with different features in newdata and training set when raining the explainer. Really not sure how to tackle that before the workshop I'm supposed to give on that on Monday ;) I'll appreciate any suggestions here!

Comment: BTW, I'm not sure if the discrepances in model class comes from different computers or just different versions of R/Rstudio/packages yet, but the differences are there, nevertheless

Comment: Right -- after some research, I realized that in newer versions of `quanteda`, `textmodel_nb` returns an object with a slightly different structure. See my updated answer. I guess you should advise your workshop participants to install the latest version of `quanteda`.

Comment: It works now, fantastic! Thanks so much for your guidance here and clarifications. It saved our workshop :) Makes me think how amazing SO, R and open source communities in general are. Thanks for being such big part of it